# Unable to locate Attribute with the given name [trackers] on this ManagedType

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lazy-initialization

I'am trying to provide Application on Spring with Lazy-Fetch relation between Entities.

Model "User":

```
     Entity
 @Table(name = "users")
 @Component
 public class User {

   @Id
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "userseq", sequenceName = "userseq", allocationSize = 1)
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "userseq")
   private Integer id;

   // Some fields/getters/setters 

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
   private List<Tracker> trakers;

 }
```

Model "Trackers"

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "trackers")
 @Component
 public class Tracker {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "tracker_seq", sequenceName = "tracker_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "tracker_seq")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private User user;

// Some fields/getters/setters 
}
```

Inherited JPA-repository with @EntityGraph. By this I'am trying to provide select user with all trackers, related with:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface CrudUserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

   @EntityGraph (attributePaths = {"trackers"}, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
   @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id=?1")
   User getByIdWithTrackers(int id);
}
```

Repository-class:

```
 @Repository
 public class AnketUserRepository implements UserRepository {

   @Autowired
   private CrudUserRepository crudRepository;

   @Override
   public User getByIdWithoutTrackers(int id) {
       return crudRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
   }

   @Override
   public User getByIdWithTrackers(int id){
       return crudRepository.getByIdWithTrackers(id);
    }

}
```

And controller:

```
@RestController ("userRestController")
@RequestMapping(value = UserRestController.USER_URL, produces = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class UserRestController extends AbstractUserController {

    public static final String USER_URL = "/customers";

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public User getByIdWithoutTrackers(@PathVariable int id) {
        return super.getByIdWithoutTrackers(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}/withTrackers")
    public User getByIdWithTrackers(@PathVariable int id) {
        return super.getByIdWithTrackers(id);
    }
 }
```

Query "/customers/1" works fine. It returns all customers without trackers (Lazy-Fetch, accordingly).

But "/customers/1/withTrackers" returns the following exception:

```
  lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [trackers] on this ManagedType [ru.spb.model.User]"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, its a stupid mistake. In User I write "trakers". But in CrudUserRepository at attributePaths  "traCkers".